# There does not exist a perfect square with all decimal digits 0 or 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

How to show that there is no  perfect square whose decimal representation consists entirely of digits 6 and 0?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean no perfect square can have a decimal representation consisting entirely of digits $6$ or $0$.  You should edit the Question to clarify this, and to add any thoughts you have about how to attack the problem (especially if you tried something that did not succeed).

Answer (score 9):

**Outline:** Well, I can think of one, namely $0$. So let us assume there is at least one $6$.

The number would have to end in an even number of $0$'s, possibly none. Remove them. The resulting number must be divisible by $4$. But a number that ends in $06$ or $66$ cannot be divisible by $4$.

Comment: Why must the resulting number after (removing the trailing zeroes) be divisible by 4.It must be a perfect square and for that it must have 4k or 4k+1 form and not 4k+2,which 06 and 66 have.

Comment: That's another way of putting it. When you say $4k$ form, I say divisible by $4$. Same thing.

Comment: I mean it necessarily has not to be divisible by 4(as you said), for leaving 1 as a remaider may still serve the purpose.

Comment: Not for a number made up of $0$'s and/or $6$'s, since remainder $1$ cannot arise.